# How to fix exe launch after installation is finished

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project, badimageformatexception

I tried to launch an application after installation is finished but it gave error of `BagImageFormat`

I tried mostly all the provided solution on stackoverflow and on different websites also like using custom action and adding installer class.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class InstallerState:System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public InstallerState()
      : base()
    {
        this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(MyInstaller_Committed);

        this.Committing += new InstallEventHandler(MyInstaller_Committing);
    }

    private void MyInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\some name.exe");
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do nothing... 
        }
    }

    // Override the 'Install' method.
    public override void Install(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Install(savedState);
    }

    // Override the 'Commit' method.
    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);
    }

    // Override the 'Rollback' method.
    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Rollback(savedState);
    }
}
```

Actually there are some ways through which i got the solution but it is not perfect solution.

As I turned off InstallerClass in custom actions the exe will be launched but the installation is still unfinished

Some gave solutions for this problem also but i can't understand those